# Align multiple answers in equation

Tags: equations, columns, alignment

I want the following nicely aligned

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    & x^2(x-1) &&= 0\\
    x^2 &= 0  \vee x-1 &&= 0\\
    x &= 0 \vee x&&=1
\end{alignat*}
```

result:

[image]

edit:
I want something like this to be the desired output. Also, i add the 0 to the solution, this was a mistake.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about alignment like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ivso.png)?

Comment: Welcome! Can you show how do you want to align the expressions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this layout?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
     x^2(x-1) = 0 \\[2ex]
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 & & (x^2 = 0) & \vee (x-1 = 0) \\
 \ArrowBetweenLines
  & & (x = 0) & \vee (x =1)
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}%\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Another layout, hopefully more like you want (same preamble):

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& & \mathllap{x^2(x-1)} & = 0 \\[1ex]
 (x^2 & = 0) \vee{} & (x-1 & = 0) \\
 (x & = 0) \vee{} & (x & =1)
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this also might be a good alternative, but still isn't the way I want to align.

Comment: @Simsa: I've posted another code. Does it suit you better?

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    x^2(x-1)=0 \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x^2=0 &\Rightarrow x=0\\ x-1=0 &\Rightarrow x=1\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Update: With an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{\ }l@{\ }l@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{x^2(x-1)}&=0\\
     x^2=0\ \vee &x-1&=0 \\
     x=0\ \vee &x &=1
     \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Sadly, this is a simplified problem and the actual equation is much longer and won't fit on the page

Comment: @Simsa I've updated the answer. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: It does, but it is very complicated haha. Thanks for the effort!